# Find and replace string in parameter bash

Tags: regex, string, bash, replace

```
$ ./myscript my.site.com
```

How do I replace all dots in the first parameter? Here's my current try but it's returning a **bad substition** error.

```
#!/bin/bash
dbname=${$1//./_}

echo $dbname
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
dbname=${1//./_}
```

Remove `$` before 1 since `$1` and `${1}` are the same.